# Unix wildcard substitution

Tags: bash, shell, unix, wildcard

I can't understand why my shell script is outputting the following and I was wondering if someone could explan what is happening.

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
thisCommand="echo"
thatCommand="echo"

LOGPATH=bar
ID=foo
thisCommand="$thisCommand \$(ls -1t $LOGPATH/$ID* )"

ID=random
thatCommand="$thatCommand \$(ls -1t $LOGPATH/$ID* )"

echo $thisCommand
echo $thatCommand
```

output:

```
echo $(ls -1t bar/foo345 bar/foo346 )
echo $(ls -1t bar/random* )
```

Where `bar/foo345` and `bar/foo346` exist but `bar/random*` doesn't.

So here the wildcard is only replicated with the actual files if they exist. Shouldn't the shell script either just stick to the wildcard or replace the flie names and ls throw an error if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Using `ls` here is very bad practice, and completely unnecessary. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `shopt` command to change this behavior:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Which will not echo `*` for some glob pattern that cannot be expanded.

As per BASH manual:

> `nullglob`
>
> If  set,  bash  allows  patterns which match no files (see
>   Pathname Expansion above) to expand to a null
>         string, rather than themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If you quote the parameter expansion, file name generation will not be attempted:

```
$ echo "$thisCommand"
echo $(ls -1t bar/foo* )
```